# Column name when using concat

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am concatenating some columns in Spark SQL using the `concat` function. Here is some dummy code:

```
   import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{concat, lit}

    val data1 = sc.parallelize(Array(2, 0, 3, 4, 5))
    val data2 = sc.parallelize(Array(4, 0, 0, 6, 7))
    val data3 = sc.parallelize(Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 10))
    val dataJoin = data1.zip(data2).zip(data3).map((x) => (x._1._1, x._1._2, x._2 )).toDF("a1","a2","a3")

    val dataConcat = dataJoin.select($"a1",concat(lit("["),$"a1", lit(","),$"a2", lit(","),$"a3", lit("]")))
```

Is there a way to specify or to change the label of the columns in order to avoid the default name which is not very practical?

```
+---+------------------------+
| a1|concat([,a1,,,a2,,,a3,])|
+---+------------------------+
|  2|                 [2,4,1]|
|  0|                 [0,0,2]|
|  3|                 [3,0,3]|
|  4|                 [4,6,4]|
|  5|                [5,7,10]|
+---+------------------------+
```

Comment: On Spark Scala notebook at http://try.jupyter.org I get a compile error on `.toDF` not a method of RDD.  Could you post your `import` statements?

Comment: I have edited the question to include the import statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [as](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html#as(java.lang.String)) or [alias](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html#alias(java.lang.String)) methods to give a name to your column.